# Eager mode optimizers

Tags: tensorflow, optimization

**Only TF native optimizers are supported in Eager mode**
I'm getting this error with every optimiser I have tried in the following:

```
def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(784,)), tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2), tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax) ])

    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
    model.compile(optimizer = opt, 
           loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics= ['accuracy']) 

    return model
```

So my question is, what is a 'TF native optimizer' please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Change from `opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` to `opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(<your desired learning rate>)`.

Longer answer: In the snippet provided above, you're passing a class (`tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`) instead of an object to `model.compile`. The error message is thus complaining that the type of the `opt` argument is incorrect.

Hope that helps.

(A [recent commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/347201aa1e866f5899d000f40251c4090bcf3c73) will hopefully result in a better error message in a future release)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ash's answer, another possible cause of the "Only TF native optimizers are supported in Eager mode" error is using a tf.keras optimizer rather than a tf.train optimizer.

For example:

```
# Gives error
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Also gives error
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Correct
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```